# "vim:filetype" equivalent in vscode

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, file-type, file-type-associations

Vim has a nice way of dictating what syntax highlighter shall be used with a specific file  (disregarding the file extension by specifying the keyword `vim:filetype` in the beginning or at the end of the file.)

Is there an equivalent way of suggesting vscode to use a syntax highlighter with a file without paying attention to its file extension?

Example: in vim

```sh
# vim:filetype=i3
set $mod Mod4
set $alt Mod1
...
```

> I am not looking for `files.associations` or the `Change Language
>   Mode` settings. I want to state the language mapping within the file itself and I understand that probably this is not a builtin feature just hoping an extension can do this
>
> **Why I am interested in this?** because many of the so-called dotfiles in Linux don't have any special extension and when you open
>   the file in another vscode instance (in another machine) you want the
>   IDE to be intelligent enough to deduce the correct syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this question has been around for quite some time now but I thought I should share that this is now possible through a third party extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrislajoie.vscode-modelines

I have not tested this myself but it has a lot of installs with absolutely no bad press so it should work properly.

Repo: https://github.com/ctlajoie/vscode-modelines

Comment: Thank you @infinityzxx, for taking the time and answering an old question. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: second this, excellent extension. I believe there's an equivilant for sublime text too.

Answer (score 1):

### If you need to persist that

You can define file associations in VS Code settings. If you open the `settings.json` you can define a map like this:

```
{
  "files.associations": {
    "main.php": "html"
  }
}
```

I'd suggest you configure this in the project `settings.json`, so it only applies to these files.

I don't know a way to configure that from the file directly though.

### If you need to do that punctually

You can change the **language mode** manually to use a different syntax highlighting for a specific file, regardless its extension. I detailed this in a recent blog post: https://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2019/12/vscode-syntax-highlight-on-copied-text/

There are different ways to do this, but I suggest you open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and type "Change Language Mode".

[image]

It will pop up the list where you can select the appropriate language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the file association and the **Change Language Mode** option. What I am looking for is a way to state the language mapping within the file itself. So when I open it in another VSCode (in another machine) it can infer the correct syntax highlighter without looking at the file extension.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean! I don't think that is possible to set the language mapping within the file itself, natively in VS Code. There seem to be a related issue in VS Code: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81610. The way I would do it today: define file associations for these specific files of the project in the workspace settings and commit the workspace settings, so they are shared. It's not ideal though.

Comment: I guess you are right and there is no builtin mechanism for this feature though I was hoping someone already has created an extension that can at least mimic what vim does since it's quite a popular standard for people to decorate their dotfiles with file associations.